# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am using JPA2.0+hibernate3.2+Spring3.0.5+MySql5.5 to implement DAO function,but it doesn't work and just throw javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException when i tried to persist entity to DB.  Please see my coding and configuration.

1.Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="booking_no")
public class BookingNo {
    public BookingNo(){
    };
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column(unique=true,length=30)
    private String prefix;
```

2.DAO

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,isolation=Isolation.DEFAULT)
    public Object generateBookingNo(String customer) throws Exception{
        logger.debug("generateBookingNo() start,generate booking no by customer:"+customer);
        if(customer == null || customer.trim().length() == 0){
            logger.error("generateBookingNo(),customer is empty,return null");
            return null;
        }
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try{
                Query query = em.createQuery("select b from BookingNo b where b.prefix='"+customer+"'");
                Object object =null;
                try{
                        object = query.getSingleResult();
                }catch(NoResultException e){
                        logger.info("generateBookingNo(),not find id for customer["+customer+"],will save a initial record");
                        BookingNo bkNo = new BookingNo();
                        bkNo.setPrefix(customer);
                        logger.debug("generateBookingNo(),the bookingNo is:"+bkNo);
                        em.persist(bkNo);
                        //em.flush();
                        Object object2 =null;
                        try{
                               object2 = em.createQuery("select b.id from BookingNo b where b.prefix='"+customer+"'").getSingleResult();
                        }catch(Exception e2){
                            logger.error("get error when query customer ["+customer+"]",e);
                            return null;
                        }
                        return  customer+"-"+object2;
                }
                if(object == null || !(object instanceof BookingNo)){
                    logger.error("generateBookingNo(),return nothing but not catch NoResultException,return null");
                    return null;
                }
                BookingNo bkNo =(BookingNo) object;
                Integer newId = bkNo.getId()+1;
                //Query query2 = em.createQuery("update BookingNo b set b.id="+newId+" where b.prefix='"+customer+"'");
                Query query2 = em.createNativeQuery("update booking_no b set b.id="+newId+" where b.prefix='"+customer+"'");
                int res = query2.executeUpdate();
                logger.debug("generateBookingNo(),the to be update bookingNo is:"+bkNo+",the update result is:"+res);
                //em.flush();
                return customer+"-"+newId;
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("get error in generateBookingNo()",e);
            return null;
        }finally{
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }
```

3.Spring cfg file

```
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">  
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="bookingEMF"/>  
</bean>  
     <bean id="dataSource1"  class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
               <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
               <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/booking"></property>
               <property name="user" value="root"></property>
               <property name="password" value="123456"></property>
               <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1"></property>
               <property name="minPoolSize" value="1"></property>
               <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"></property>
               <property name="maxIdleTime" value="60"></property>
               <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5"></property>
               <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60"></property>
               <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="20"></property>
               <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="true"></property>
</bean>
    <!-- Entity Manager Factory -->
     <bean id="bookingEMF" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
                <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="booking"/>  
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
                <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
                <property name="jpaPropertyMap">  
                   <map>  
                         <entry key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion"     value="true"/> 
                         <entry key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session"  value="true"/>  
                         <entry key="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="auto"/> 
                          <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/> 
                          <entry key="format_sql" value="true"/> 
                         <!-- <entry key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup"/>   -->
                   </map>  
                </property> 
    </bean>
    <!-- JPA Vendor,Implementation is hibernate -->
     <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>

                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </bean>
    <!-- DAO -->
    <bean id="BookingDAO" class="com.chailie.booking.dao.impl.booking.BookingDAO" >
                <property name="emf" ref="bookingEMF"/>
    </bean>
```

when run junit test case as following

```
@Test
    public void testGenerateBookingNo(){
        try {
            BookingDAO dao  = (BookingDAO) DAOFactory.getDAO("BookingDAO", DAOFactory.TYPE_APPLICATION);
            dao.generateBookingNo("chailie");
            //dao.generateBookingNo("chailie2");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            logger.error("get error",e);
        }

    }
```

It will occur javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException and i don't know what happeded,does anybody could help to solve this?i really appreciate it
By the way,please see my log

```
23:15:46.817 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
23:15:46.837 [main] DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - HQL: select b from com.chailie.booking.model.booking.BookingNo b where b.prefix='chailie'
23:15:46.837 [main] DEBUG o.h.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - SQL: select bookingno0_.id as id0_, bookingno0_.prefix as prefix0_ from booking_no bookingno0_ where bookingno0_.prefix='chailie'
23:15:46.837 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
23:15:46.856 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
23:15:46.856 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - opening JDBC connection
23:15:46.891 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select bookingno0_.id as id0_, bookingno0_.prefix as prefix0_ from booking_no bookingno0_ where bookingno0_.prefix='chailie' limit ?
Hibernate: select bookingno0_.id as id0_, bookingno0_.prefix as prefix0_ from booking_no bookingno0_ where bookingno0_.prefix='chailie' limit ?
23:15:46.922 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
23:15:46.926 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - result row: EntityKey[com.chailie.booking.model.booking.BookingNo#8]
23:15:46.935 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close ResultSet (open ResultSets: 1, globally: 1)
23:15:46.936 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
23:15:46.936 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing JDBC connection
23:15:46.936 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
23:15:46.939 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad - resolving associations for [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.BookingNo#8]
23:15:46.941 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad - done materializing entity [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.BookingNo#8]
23:15:46.942 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.StatefulPersistenceContext - initializing non-lazy collections
23:15:46.942 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing JDBC connection
23:15:46.944 [main] DEBUG o.h.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl - mark transaction for rollback
23:15:46.954 [main] ERROR c.c.b.d.booking.impl.BookingDAOTest - get error in generateBookingNo()
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:48) [hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar:3.4.0.GA]
    at com.chailie.booking.dao.impl.booking.BookingDAO.generateBookingNo(BookingDAO.java:104) [classes/:na]
    at com.chailie.booking.dao.impl.booking.BookingDAO$$FastClassByCGLIB$$2898182b.invoke(<generated>) [cglib-2.2.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191) [cglib-2.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) [spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.chailie.booking.dao.impl.booking.BookingDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$58d6a935.generateBookingNo(<generated>) [cglib-2.2.jar:na]
    at com.chailie.booking.dao.booking.impl.BookingDAOTest.testGenerateBookingNo(BookingDAOTest.java:42) [test-classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_15]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_15]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_15]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_15]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44) [junit-4.7.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15) [junit-4.7.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41) [junit-4.7.jar:na]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20) [junit-4.7.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76) [junit-4.7.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50) [junit-4.7.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193) [junit-4.7.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52) [junit-4.7.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191) [junit-4.7.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42) [junit-4.7.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184) [junit-4.7.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236) [junit-4.7.jar:na]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53) [surefire-junit4-2.10.jar:2.10]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123) [surefire-junit4-2.10.jar:2.10]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104) [surefire-junit4-2.10.jar:2.10]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_15]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_15]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_15]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_15]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164) [surefire-api-2.10.jar:2.10]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110) [surefire-booter-2.10.jar:2.10]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175) [surefire-booter-2.10.jar:2.10]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107) [surefire-booter-2.10.jar:2.10]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68) [surefire-booter-2.10.jar:2.10]
23:15:46.958 [main] INFO  o.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - closing
23:15:46.960 [main] DEBUG o.h.transaction.JDBCTransaction - commit
23:15:46.962 [main] DEBUG o.h.transaction.JDBCTransaction - re-enabling autocommit
23:15:46.962 [main] DEBUG o.h.transaction.JDBCTransaction - committed JDBC Connection
23:15:46.962 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing JDBC connection
23:15:46.963 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Spring, but should't you begin a transaction before doing a save?

Comment: @galuano1 You are correct, but the `TransactionManager` should handle it. The question is: is it correctly configured? Chailie, can you show the Test class configuration?

Comment: Hi,Sotirios,Which test class configuration do you mean?if you were saying junit4 test class,then it is just a normal juint class ,By the way,i heard someone said that need to add additional configuration for junit test case to let it support spring configuration,e.g something like @RunWith(Spring...),sorry,i can't remember the full name,is that true?

Answer (score 2):

Before you do a `em.persist()`, get a `EntityTransaction` object (say `et`), by doing `em.getTransaction()`, and then do a `et.begin()`. After you are done with the `em.persist()`, do a `et.commit()`.

Comment: I am using spring AOP Transaction,e.g @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,isolation=Isolation.DEFAULT),Such that i don't think i need to open/commit transaction manually.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager() I think you need to use EntityManager.getTransaction() manually as well.

Why not inject a Spring managed EntityManager instead of the factory?

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="booking")
EntityManager em;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your DAOFactory a Spring Managed Bean? Is your JUnit running with Spring's Runner or is it aware of the application context?

What it looks like to me is that the code is actually running outside of Spring from the data provided, indicating that there is no support for the Transaction Proxy you are trying to create, ie it is being ignored.

try using this in your junit (you will need spring-test)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("spring-cfg.xml")
public class TestClass(){

    @Autowired
    private DAOFactory daoFactory;
```

Now you will need to configure your DAOFactory to be a Spring Bean and it shouldn't use new to create your BookingDAO, instead that should be injected via Spring into the DAOFactory for it to serve, granted with Spring you really shouldn't need this type of logic.

Comment: Thanks for your attention,my DAOFactory  is just hold a static application context reference,it provides an API which named getDAO,when invoking it,it will get corresponding DAO from spring context via the DAO name,so i did't use new to create DAO and still get the DAO from spring context in nature,by the way,when i deploy my DAO to tomcat to try same case,it still  have same problem,i really doubt it is just junit's problem,what i can do now is open transaction manually before peisist or executeUpdate(),but that's not a good way,after all,i am using spring AOP to manager the transaction.

Comment: Please see my DAOFactory:                                        private static ApplicationContext context= new ClasspathXMLApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

public static AbstractDAO getDAO(String DAOName)
{
  return (AbstractDAO)context.getBean(DAOName);
}

Comment: So you are creating a new application context in your DAO factory and trying to tie the transaction to an existing transaction. I am not really following your code. The Transaction Manager defined in your primary application context should be used the entire time, if you create a new application context you are outside the proxy of the first transaction so you aren't in a transaction because the DAO is outside the proxy

Comment: But if i don't create a new application context in my DAOFactory,then how to initialize the application context?beside this point,the application context is also a global variable in DAOFactory

Comment: My handler is:1.Run junit test case 2.get BookingDAO from DAOFactory 3.in DAOFactory,it has one global static variable "ApplicationContext" which just instantiated for once,it will return BookingDAO via bean id,e.g context.getBean("BookingDAO") 4.invoke BookingDAO's generateBookingNo() function,this method is supposed to use spring AOP transaction to manage the transaction,e.g @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,isolation=Isolation.DEFAULT)
    public Object generateBookingNo(String customer) throws Exception{ ...5.In generateBookingNo(),get entity manager and persist object

Comment: Hi,This problem really bother me a lot,can you suggest some tutorial of using JPA+hibernate+spring+JpaTransactionManager?thanks very much

Comment: Yes I can, but first of all let me know your container. Are you running this in a web application container ultimately or as a java executable (this will also answer how to create your application context). You actually don't need a reference to the application context, your container/process does. The context gives you what you need, you should never have to ask the context for anything.

Comment: At first,i run this in Eclipse junit4 enviroment,it has that exception,then i change to run it in tomcat,this is how i get DAO from application context:public static AbstractDAO getDAO(String DAOName) throws Exception{
   return (AbstractDAO) ContextLoaderListener.getCurrentWebApplicationContext().getBean(DAOName+"DAO");
 }
 .I am at home now,i also could how you tomcat log

Comment: Sorry,The log is too long and i can't show you full log,please see the suspicious log which i think :21:45:32,986  INFO TransactionManagerLookupFactory:33 - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
21:45:32,987  INFO SettingsFactory:134 - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
21:45:32,987  INFO SettingsFactory:138 - Automatic session close at end of transaction: enabled
21:45:32,988  INFO SettingsFactory:145 - JDBC batch size: 15

Comment: Please see this one too,21:45:33,057  INFO SettingsFactory:81 - RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.5.20
21:45:33,057  INFO SettingsFactory:82 - JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.10 ( Revision: ${svn.Revision} )
21:45:33,059  INFO Dialect:151 - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
21:45:33,060  INFO TransactionFactoryFactory:34 - Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory